# Is it possible to influence the working behaviour of a simple dc motor with an outside electromagnet?

Tags: dc-motor, electromagnetism, magnetics, electromagnetic

I am using a simple DC-Motor 9V like this [one](https://www.conrad.de/de/p/motraxx-x-fly-400-flugmodell-brushed-elektromotor-15800-u-min-229115.html?WT.mc_id=google_pla&WT.srch=1&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIjMWUxaKg5QIV2eFRCh2BtgwwEAQYBCABEgImd_D_BwE:G:s&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjMWUxaKg5QIV2eFRCh2BtgwwEAQYBCABEgImd_D_BwE&hk=SEM&s_kwcid=AL!222!3!326955887690!!!g!!). Now, I am curious about what influence an outside magnet / magnetic field would have on the working behavior of this motor?

I would like to use the following [electromagnet](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Electromagnet-p-1820.html). Is this appropriate to influence the motor or do I probably need a stronger one?

What would probably happen if I turn on the electromagnet near to the motor?

Could I influence the behavior of the motor by randomly turning on and off this electromagnet in a fashion such as a very short period of time (e.g., 10ms on every second)? What would probably happen?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Motors are generally designed to conduct and contain their magnetic flux in a way that as much flux as possible is used for driving the motor and little is lost. As a consequence, flux supplied externally will not easily penetrate the motor. Therefore, a very strong magnet would be required to have much effect when applied externally to a motor.

It is possible that strong magnetic pulses applied externally could cause cause torque and speed variations. The most effective way to get an external magnetic field to penetrate the motor is to position the entire motor in the path of the external flux. The flux path for the linked electromagnet is between the center rod and the outer ring. To have an effect, you would need something like an iron U shape, with the coil wound around the legs and the entire motor in the opening at the top.